# Why is $\sqrt{-8}\times\sqrt{-2}=-4$

Tags: complex-numbers

> ***Why is $\sqrt{-8}\times\sqrt{-2}=-4$***

[[image: <span class=]$\sqrt{-8}\times\sqrt{-2}=-4$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbli9.png)

Comment: $$2\sqrt 2i×i\sqrt 2=4i^2=-4$$

Comment: Define $i=\sqrt{-1}$, $i^2 = -1$, hence $\sqrt{-8}=\sqrt{8}i$, $\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{2}i$, $\sqrt{-8} \times \sqrt{-2} = \sqrt{8} i \times \sqrt{2} i = \sqrt{16} i^2 = -4$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the correct answer is $-4$.

If you are in case, wondering about why this is not equal to $\sqrt{16}=4$, its becuase

$$\sqrt{xy}=\sqrt x\sqrt y$$ if and only if at least one of $x,y$ is non negative